# Basis of a Tychonoff space

Tags: general-topology

I have read a paper. In that paper state that every Tychonoff space has a basis consisting of $F_{\sigma}$ sets.

I do not know how to prove it. Any one can help me?

Answer (score 1):

Let $\mathscr{B}$ be any base for the Tikhonov space $X$. (For example, $\mathscr{B}$ could be the entire family of non-empty open sets in $X$.) For each $x\in X$ and $B\in\mathscr{B}$ with $x\in B$ there is a continuous $f_{x,B}:X\to[0,1]$ such that $f(x)=0$ and $f(y)=1$ whenever $y\in X\setminus B$. Let

$$U_{x,B}=\{y\in X:f_{x,B}(y)<1\}\;;$$

then $U_{x,B}$ is an $F_\sigma$-set such that $x\in U_{x,B}\subseteq B$, so $\{U_{x,B}:x\in B\in\mathscr{B}\}$ is a base for $X$ consisting of $F_\sigma$-sets.

**Added:** To see that $U_{x,B}$ is an $F_\sigma$-set, note that

$$U_{x,B}=\bigcup_{q\in\Bbb Q\cap(0,1)}\{y\in X:f_{x,B}(y)\le q\}\;.$$

$\Bbb Q\cap(0,1)$ is countable, and each $\{y\in X:f_{x,B}(y)\le q\}$ is closed in $X$ by the continuity of $f_{x,B}$.

Comment: Why is $U_{x,B}$ an $F_{\sigma}$- set?

Comment: @lolo: I was hoping that you’d see that on your own, but I’ll add it to my answer.